# Почему после i = 5 выводится одинаковый результат?

Tags: c, математика, численные-методы

Недавно начал изучать C, не могу понять, почему после `i = 5` выводится одинаковый результат?

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>  
#define SIZE 100  

int main()  
{  
   int x = 2;  
   float y[SIZE] = {1, 0};  

   for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)  
   {  
      y[i + 1] = 1.5 * y[i] - 0.5 * x * pow( y[i], 3 );  
      printf("%.5f\n", y[i]);  
   }  

   return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что вы решаете методом последовательных приближений уравнение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и достигаете нужного корня - `y=sqrt(0.5)`. Все нормально, сходящаяся к корню последовательность значений.

Зачем для этого нужен массив - непонятно, но это уже второй вопрос.

P.S. А чего вы ждали?...

P.P.S. А вообще - всегда надо задавать вопрос верно. Например, если код не то выводит - то надо как минимум поставить задачу (*что должен делать код*), ваш способ решения, что вы от него ждете и что получаете, и почему это не то, что вы ждете...

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение, теперь буду использовать ваш подход.

Comment: @DaniilKuchuk если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: Надо еще рассказать, почему не сходится к нолю, который тоже решение уравнения. Или к -√½ ))

Comment: @Mikhailo Ну, это долгая история - рассказывать курс численных методов :)